# python operation on sub-dimension of a numpy array

Tags: performance, pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array

A lot of numpy functions provide the option to operate over certain axis with axis= parameter. My question is

1. How this 'along axis' operations are implemented? Or, more direct question
2. How do I efficiently write my own function providing the similar option?

I notice numpy provides a function [numpy.apply_along_axis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html#numpy-apply-along-axis) that will serve as an answer if the base function input is 1-D array.

But what if my base function needs a multi-dimensional input? E.g. to find the 2-D moving average B of an np matrix A of shape (5,6,2,3,4) along the first two dimensions (5,6)? Like a generic function B = f_moving_mean(A, axis=(0,1))

My current solution is to use numpy.swapaxes and numpy.reshape to accomplish this. A sample code for a 1-D moving-average function being:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def nanmoving_mean(data,window,axis=0):
    kw = {'center':True,'window':window,'min_periods':1}
    if len(data.shape)==1:
        return pd.Series(data).rolling(**kw).mean().as_matrix()
    elif len(data.shape)>=2:
        tmp = np.swapaxes(data,0,axis)
        tmpshp = tmp.shape
        tmp = np.reshape( tmp, (tmpshp[0],-1), order='C' )
        tmp = pd.DataFrame(tmp).rolling(**kw).mean().as_matrix()
        tmp = np.reshape( tmp, tmpshp, order='C' )
        return np.swapaxes(tmp,0,axis)
    else:
        print('Invalid dimension!')
        return None

data = np.random.randint(10,size=(2,3,6))
print(data)
nanmoving_mean(data,window=3,axis=2)
```

Is this a common / efficient way of implementation for the question 2? Any improving / suggestion / new method is welcome.

PS. The reason I'm involving pandas here is that its rolling(...).mean() method is able to deal with nan data properly.

Edit:
I guess another way of asking the question could be: What's the syntax of looping over 'dynamical' number of dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could have an approach using [`2D` convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution).

The basic steps would be :

- As pre-processing step, replace `NaNs` with `0s` as we need to do  windowed summation on the input data.
- Get the windowed summations with [`Scipy's convolve2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) for the data values
  and also the mask of `NaNs`. We will use boundary elements as zeros.
- Subtract the windowed count of `NaNs` from the window size to get count of valid elements responsible for summations.
- For the boundary elements, we would have gradually lesser elements accounting for the summations.

Now, these `intervaled-summations` could also be obtained by [`Scipy's`1D`uniform-filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.uniform_filter1d.html) that is comparatively more efficient. Other benefit is that we could specify the axis along which these summations/averaging are to be performed.

With a mix of Scipy's `2D convolution` and `1D uniform filter`, we would have few approaches as listed next.

Import relevant Scipy functions -

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d as conv2
from scipy.ndimage.filters import uniform_filter1d as uniff
```

**Approach #1 :**

```
def nanmoving_mean_numpy(data, W): # data: input array, W: Window size
    N = data.shape[-1]
    hW = (W-1)//2

    nan_mask = np.isnan(data)
    data1 = np.where(nan_mask,0,data)

    value_sums = conv2(data1.reshape(-1,N),np.ones((1,W)),'same', boundary='fill')
    nan_sums = conv2(nan_mask.reshape(-1,N),np.ones((1,W)),'same', boundary='fill')

    value_sums.shape = data.shape
    nan_sums.shape = data.shape

    b_sizes = hW+1+np.arange(hW) # Boundary sizes
    count = np.hstack(( b_sizes , W*np.ones(N-2*hW), b_sizes[::-1] ))
    return value_sums/(count - nan_sums)
```

**Approach #2 :**

```
def nanmoving_mean_numpy_v2(data, W): # data: input array, W: Window size    
    N = data.shape[-1]
    hW = (W-1)//2

    nan_mask = np.isnan(data)
    data1 = np.where(nan_mask,0,data)

    value_sums = uniff(data1,size=W, axis=-1, mode='constant')*W
    nan_sums = conv2(nan_mask.reshape(-1,N),np.ones((1,W)),'same', boundary='fill')
    nan_sums.shape = data.shape

    b_sizes = hW+1+np.arange(hW) # Boundary sizes
    count = np.hstack(( b_sizes , W*np.ones(N-2*hW,dtype=int), b_sizes[::-1] ))
    out =  value_sums/(count - nan_sums)
    out = np.where(np.isclose( count, nan_sums), np.nan, out)
    return out
```

**Approach #3 :**

```
def nanmoving_mean_numpy_v3(data, W): # data: input array, W: Window size
    N = data.shape[-1]
    hW = (W-1)//2

    nan_mask = np.isnan(data)
    data1 = np.where(nan_mask,0,data)    
    nan_avgs = uniff(nan_mask.astype(float),size=W, axis=-1, mode='constant')

    b_sizes = hW+1+np.arange(hW) # Boundary sizes
    count = np.hstack(( b_sizes , W*np.ones(N-2*hW), b_sizes[::-1] ))
    scale = ((count/float(W)) - nan_avgs)
    out = uniff(data1,size=W, axis=-1, mode='constant')/scale
    out = np.where(np.isclose( scale, 0), np.nan, out)
    return out
```

**Runtime test**

Dataset #1 :

```
In [807]: # Create random input array and insert NaNs
     ...: data = np.random.randint(10,size=(20,30,60)).astype(float)
     ...: 
     ...: # Add 10% NaNs across the data randomly
     ...: idx = np.random.choice(data.size,size=int(data.size*0.1),replace=0)
     ...: data.ravel()[idx] = np.nan
     ...: 
     ...: W = 5 # Window size
     ...: 

In [808]: %timeit nanmoving_mean(data,window=W,axis=2)
     ...: %timeit nanmoving_mean_numpy(data, W)
     ...: %timeit nanmoving_mean_numpy_v2(data, W)
     ...: %timeit nanmoving_mean_numpy_v3(data, W)
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 22.3 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.31 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.99 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.76 ms per loop
```

Dataset #2 [Bigger dataset] :

```
In [811]: # Create random input array and insert NaNs
 ...: data = np.random.randint(10,size=(120,130,160)).astype(float)
 ...: 
 ...: # Add 10% NaNs across the data randomly
 ...: idx = np.random.choice(data.size,size=int(data.size*0.1),replace=0)
 ...: data.ravel()[idx] = np.nan
 ...: 

In [812]: %timeit nanmoving_mean(data,window=W,axis=2)
     ...: %timeit nanmoving_mean_numpy(data, W)
     ...: %timeit nanmoving_mean_numpy_v2(data, W)
     ...: %timeit nanmoving_mean_numpy_v3(data, W)
     ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 796 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 486 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 275 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 161 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Without getting too much into your question, here's the key part of the `apply_along_axis` function (viewed via Ipython)

```
        res = func1d(arr[tuple(i.tolist())], *args, **kwargs)
        outarr[tuple(ind)] = res
```

They construct two index objects, `i`, and `ind` which are varied.  Assume we specify `axis=2`, then this code does

```
outarr[i,j,l] = func1d( arr[i,j,:,l], ...)
```

for all possible values of `i`,`j`, and `l`.  So there's lots of code for a rather basic iterative calculation.

```
ind = [0]*(nd-1)   # ind is just a nd-1 list

i = zeros(nd, 'O')        # i is a 1d array with a `slice` object
i[axis] = slice(None, None)
```

I'm not familiar with the pandas `rolling`.  But there are number of `numpy` rolling-mean questions.  `scipy.signal.convolve2d` might be of use.  `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` also is used.

You idea of using `reshape` and `swapaxis` (or `transpose`) to reduce the complexity of the dimension space is also good.

(this isn't a solution; rather throw out some ideas that come to mind, remembering other 'moving average' questions.  It's too late to develop more.)

Comment: I don't where to look at the code of apply_along_axis, but how does it construct i and ind?

Comment: @ShichuZhu If you are looking for performance, `apply_along_axis` won't help.

Comment: @Divakar If the base function only deal with 1D then looping over all other dimension is the only way. Unless revise the base function to include vectorized operation i guess?

Comment: @ShichuZhu No need to loop. There are many vectorized options available to sum elems in windows.